# check 2 file check sum, for detecting any differences between them

Tags: c#, windows, backup

We have many files (word, excel) in our systems on a local network. We get backup from these files every day. Now I want to know: is a file different from it's backup or not? For example, suppose we have a file, "test.docx" and it's backup name is "test_backup.docx", I want to know that if a user makes any change on "test.docx" or not? I would like to compare these two files.

One way is to compare these files word by word, and when a difference is detected, we can conclude that file is updated.

Now my question is, is any other way such as check sum, for detecting this difference? and with this method can I find where is the update occurred?

Thanks.

Comment: Checksum is usually a good way to check if files are the same, but it won't tell you anything about how the files are different from one another. Make sure you check if the file-size is the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155)?

It sounds like you want to automate a backup copy process and you don't really care about the particular differences, just trying to determine if there are any. My answer is based on that presumption.

Hashing is a good approach to determine if a file should *really* be backed up but it requires reading the whole file and performing an expensive task on it.

You can pre-process the backup file list by looking at files' size and timestamps - modified, accessed: if they don't match - back it up without checksum. If they match then it's up to you to assume they are the same or to hash the contents, I'd try first assuming they are the same if all timestamps and size matches the backup copy and if this heuristic proves wrong - resort to hashing, but find the [fastest algorithm possible](http://code.google.com/p/xxhash/) - your application of hashes doesn't seem to require high security but rather high performance, SHA and MD5 would both be an overkill with dreadful performance

Comment: Thanks for your reply:), but it is important for me to know the location of difference, do you have nay suggestion? Thanks

Comment: You need to explain how you're using the location of the difference and its significance. Are xlsx and docx the only two file types?

Comment: For exact placement of changes you can use Track Changes in Office products and you can still use timestamps and sizes to determine which files to look at. It's also easy to programmatically accept all changes in a docx or xmlx file when you need a final version for publishing

Comment: can you explain "track changes" with an example? I can't find any example in C#, that show the changes places in a document. Thanks

Comment: Track Changes is a feature in Office products that lets you see what has been changed in a document and by whom. In C# you can check/delete the tracked changes with OpenXML SDK from microsoft, but it works only on docx and xlsx files

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we compute a signature of a file:

```
public static string Signature(this FileInfo input)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransform = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(input.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
    byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    string hash = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransform.ComputeHash(data)).Replace("-", "");
    reader.Close();
    fs.Close();
    return hash;
}
```

Then, we compute that signature against signature of previous version to detect changes.